# typescript で、 string を特殊化したい

Tags: typescript

既存のサードパーティ api に対する型付けを行っていると、例えば特殊な形式の文字列がサーバーから return される場合があります。例えば、json文字列のような。

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

このようなフィールドに対しては、 api の戻り値の型として、単純な`string`を定義するのではなく、例えば`json_string` のような型を定義して、これは以下の用途で利用可能であってほしいと思っています。

1. `string` が代入可能な所には代入できる
2. `string` が持っているメソッド・プロパティを呼び出せる
3. ただの `string` を `json_string` に対しては代入できない

これができると何が嬉しいかというと、その特定の形式の文字列を前提とした関数を定義する際に、間違ったフィールド・値をそこに代入してしまうのを防ぐことができます。

## 質問

上記のように、 string を特殊化したような型を定義したいのですが、これは可能でしょうか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

今回やりたかったことは幽霊型(Phantom Type)に近いと思い探していたところ、以下の記事を発見しました。

https://zenn.dev/f_subal/articles/phantom_type_in_typescript

これを参考に、

```
type json_string = string & { _jsonBrand: never }
```

が自分の欲しかったものだ、と思っています。

この `_ほげほげBrand` という命名規則のフィールドは、こういった型の色付けを行いたい場合に付与するフィールドとして、 typescript の内部ライブラリでも利用されているものであるそうです。

参考: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/nominaltyping#using-interfaces

Answer (score 1):

これが「できた」/「可能」と言えるか分かりませんが
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/ja/play) で試すと, `let o: object = 'hello'` だとエラーになり, `let o: object = 'hello' as Object` で通ります。
このあたりの動作がよくわからないので, 適当な部分が含まれています

```js
type json_string = string & {
  toObj: (s:json_string) => any
}

let o: object = 'hello' as Object
let s: string = 'abc'
let js: json_string = 'abc' as json_string  // Type Assertionなしだとエラー
s = js
o = js
js = s // エラー, Type Assertion付けると通る

function fn(arg: string): string {
  return arg
}

// どちらも通る
fn(s)
fn(js)
```